# How do you add an additional column to pie chart legend in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I am re-building a Crystal Report in SSRS. This is how I need the legend to render:

[image]

This is how the legend renders currently:

[image]

How do I add the number values to the legend in SSRS??

Comment: Do you pass percentage values for this chart or regular values converted to percentages ?

Comment: The percentages are created in an expression field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right click on your chart
2. Go to Series Properties
3. Go to Label tab
4. Choose  f(x) button next to "Custom legend text"
5. Type expression like: `=Fields!yourCategory.Value & " " & Fields!quantity.Value`

or

When you are not passing Percentages values from your dataset:

1. Paste this `#AXISLABEL #PERCENT` in "Custom legend text"

Comment: No problem. Glad it works. Check also my second solution (answer edited) - it doesn't require to pass percentages values from the dataset.